# Is it true that in simple rings every regular element is invertible?

Tags: ring-theory

$r$ is regular element of ring $R$ if $rx=0$ implies $x=0$ or $xr=0$ implies $x=0$. I think this is true in  matrix rings over divition ring or maybe in all artinian simple rings.

Comment: It is even a property of (two-sided) Artinian rings, and more.

Answer (score 2):

No.  [There exists a simple domain that is not  a division ring](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=3&H=8&L=2), namely they first Weyl algebra.

All nonzero elements are regular, but not all of them are invertible.